# CGContext clips more than it should

Tags: ios, cgcontext

I have a `UIView` that has 3 custom subviews whose class is called (for now) `LVStemp` and that represent nodes in a tree. An `LVStemp`'s frame is larger than the node itself because it will also include some drawing that lies outside the node (not coded yet). `LVStemp` has a property called `nodeFrame` that represents the frame of the node itself, in the main view's coordinates.

I'm trying to draw the nodes and fill them with a gradient. But the gradient is clipping in a way that is not what I intend. The result looks like this:

[image]

The top node is filled correctly but the bottom two are not.

Setting up, in the `UIView`'s superview:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 350, 350)];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];

    LVStemp *node1 = [[LVStemp alloc] init];
    node1.frame = CGRectMake(75, 0, 50, 50);
    node1.nodeFrame = node1.frame;
    node1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [myView addSubview:node1];

    LVStemp *node2 = [[LVStemp alloc] init];
    node2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 25, 100, 175);
    node2.nodeFrame = CGRectMake(0, 150, 50, 50);
    node2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [myView addSubview:node2];

    LVStemp *node3 = [[LVStemp alloc] init];
    node3.frame = CGRectMake(100, 25, 100, 175);
    node3.nodeFrame = CGRectMake(150, 150, 50, 50);
    node3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [myView addSubview:node3];
}
```

My code in `LVStemp.h`:

```
@interface LVStemp : UIView

@property (nonatomic) CGRect nodeFrame; 

@end
```

My code in `LVStemp.m`:

```
@implementation LVStemp

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Build nodeBounds (= nodeFrame converted to self's coordinate system)
    CGRect nodeBounds = [self convertRect:self.nodeFrame fromView:self.superview];

    // Get CGContextRef
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Draw node with gradient
    [self drawEllipseInRect:nodeBounds withGradient:context];
}

- (void)drawEllipseInRect:(CGRect)rect withGradient:(CGContextRef)context
{
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    CGFloat colors[] = {
        0.1, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0,
        0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 1.0
    };

    CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors, NULL, 2);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace), baseSpace = NULL;

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect);
    CGContextClip(context);

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxX(rect));

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient), gradient = NULL;

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}

@end
```

(`drawEllipseInRect:withGradient:` is adapted from [here](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/learn-objectivec-building-an-app-part-8-/100).)

And here's what happens if I comment out the clipping part:

```
    //CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect);
    //CGContextClip(context);
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context is clipped correct, but you are drawing the gradient at the wrong Position:

```
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxX(rect));
```

Change that to use maxY:

```
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
```

But as you might have noticed, the strokes are being clipped. That's because they are drawn centered on the given outline. You might consider calling it with some inset:

```
[self drawEllipseInRect:CGRectInset(nodeBounds, lineWidth/2, lineWidth/2) withGradient:context];
```

Comment: Argh! Thanks, @robert. Thought I was missing something fundamental about CGContext -- turns out it was just a typo. Thanks for catching, and for the tip about CGRectInset.

Comment: You're welcome. This happens often enough to me due to xCodes autocompletion ;)